# Where are my custom Photoshop CS4 actions on Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, adobe-photoshop, photoshop-cs4

I upgraded my HDD and I'm trying to import from the old one my custom user-generated actions (and some imported) which I had in Photoshop CS4. Which I can't find.

I have looked in

```
/Applications/Adobe Photoshop CS4/Presets/Actions  
/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Adobe Photoshop CS4  
~/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Adobe Photoshop CS4/Presets/Actions
```

And there's no `~/Library/Preferences/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User generated actions don't get saved anywhere where you can physically grab a file and import into photoshop. It's an embedded setting. Although, you can export your actions from the actions palette and save it to a file which you can then import into the new hard drive. (Same with custom made shapes)